# Is it possible to upload files *sequentially* via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I've successfully implemented the uploading of directory structures with Fine Uploader using the dragAndDrop: reportDirectoryPaths option. Each file that is uploaded has it's qqpath property to signify the path from which it came.

```
var exampleUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
    template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
    request: {
        endpoint: '/api/UploadDocuments',
        params: {
            param1: "Test1",
            param2: "Test2"
        }
    },
    callbacks: {
        onComplete: function (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) {
            console.log("onComplete");
        },
        onAllComplete: function (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) {
            console.log("onAllComplete");
        }
    },
    multiple: true,
    dragAndDrop: {
        reportDirectoryPaths: true
    },
    autoUpload: true,
    debug: false
});
```

There is however, one problem: the files are uploaded one by one, but the ajax request is called sometimes at the same time. If two files with the same directory structure are passed to the service at the exact same time, the directories might be created twice in one go. Is there a way to only do the ajax request on success of the previous? In other words, is there a way to upload the files sequentially, rather than at the same time (a whole bunch of files being passed into the service at once)?

Thanks in advance,
aj

Comment: sure, just have the `success` handler of the ajax call re-call itself (e.g. recursion). so call #1 uploads file #1. when that call returns, it calls itself again and starts file #2, etc... on the other hand, this can be inefficient/slow since you're doing a seperate http upload for each file. you could just include sequencing data with the files so the server can tell which it is. e.g. `file1=sometext; file2=othertext` and have the serve extract the number from the name: `file1` -> `1`, "ah, this is the first file, create directory #2", then "ah, this is file 2, so create directory #1"

Comment: have you tried doing this with Fine Uploader or are you familiar with the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is an issue with your server, and not with anything client/browser-side. It's shortsighted to limit your frontend to one request at a time. This presents a completely unnecessary bottleneck. Your server should sort all of this out.

On approach is to keying uploaded files by the UUID assigned by Fine Uploader and then sort out the storage hierarchy later. And if you don't want to trust the UUID supplied by Fine Uploader, you can always generate your own server-side, return it with the response, and Fine Uploader will use that for all other requests related to that specific file instead.

Another approach is for your server to simply check server side to see if the directory already exists for the target file.

Keep in mind that this "qqPath" property you are depending on only exists in Chrome/Opera, and only when a directory is dropped.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. are you saying that there isn't a way to wait for success response before uploading another file? i understand what you're saying and you make a lot of good points. how can this be implemented with a RESTful service? and assuming we do what you mentioned, how would our server know when the uploads are truly complete (whether there's 30 or 40 files)?

Comment: I'm saying there is no good reason to wait for a success response before uploading another file in your case, as far as I can tell. You know when the uploads are complete client-side. Fine Uploader will call your [`onAllComplete` callback handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#allComplete). At that point, you can notify your server. This will be fired when a group of files submitted are all done uploading.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload files one by one using fine uploader the easiest way is limiting the max connections to 1.

```
var exampleUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
    template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
    request: {
        endpoint: '/api/UploadDocuments',
        params: {
            param1: "Test1",
            param2: "Test2"
        }
    },
    callbacks: {
        onComplete: function (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) {
            console.log("onComplete");
        },
        onAllComplete: function (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) {
            console.log("onAllComplete");
        }
    },
    maxConnections: 1,
    multiple: true,
    dragAndDrop: {
        reportDirectoryPaths: true
    },
    autoUpload: true,
    debug: false
});
```

By default the parameter maxConnections is 3.